# Magento 1.9.3 Login and register not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In my shop login and register its not working:

http://makishoc.nextmp.net/customer/account/login/

http://makishoc.nextmp.net/customer/account/create/

I'm sure that forms have input "form_key" with

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

And my cookie configuration it's like this:

[image]

Has anyone seen this problem before and can point me to the error?

Comment: Make sure your server is not running out of space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors which need to be corrected:

1) You have lastname required in the create account section which is hidden. Either display that field or remove required from database.

2) Also you have "Associate to website" field which is required.

Please solve these error and you will able to create account and in the same way you will also be able to login.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this code in form_key `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

Comment: can you share me your magento link?

Comment: increase cookie lifetime to 86400